# Are ec2 instances created by default in default VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I opened my AWS account in 2016 but did not use much. Last week I created 2 t2.nano instances which happen to be in some VPC (not Classic EC2). Is this default VPC?  But when I go to VPC dashboard for that vpc (the only vpc in my account), the value for attribute Default VPC is No. I am confused. I do not remember ever creating custom VPC. Can some one explain?

IPV4 CIDR value for this VPC is 172.30.0.0/16

Comment: What is the IP of your instance. Default VPC start with `172.31.*.*`. Custom ones are usually `10.*.*.*`.

Comment: VPC could be created as part of other resources you created. For example, when you created RDS instance, you could tick an option to automatically create a VPC for you. Or maybe someone else did it? Are you sure no one else uses the account?

Comment: i m the only one using the account

Comment: If you have CloudTrial enabled you can go through its logs looking for VPC specific API calls. Once located, you should be able to identify who/what/when did create the custom VPC.